# Cython: Assigning single element to multidimensional memory view slice

Tags: python, python-3.x, slice, cython, memoryview

Cython appears to use a wrong striding whenever I assign a single value to a slice of a multi-dimensional memory view, except when the slice is along the first dimension. I give a complete example below:

```
# bug.py
import numpy as np

def bug():
    #cdef int[:, ::1] a
    a = 2*np.ones((2, 2), dtype=np.intc)
    a[:, :1] = 1
    print(np.asarray(a))
```

If we run this in Python (e.g. `python3 -c 'import bug; bug.bug()'`), we get

```
[[1 2]
 [1 2]]
```

printed out, as expected. I now compile it with Cython by renaming the file to `bug.pyx`, have the following saved in a `Makefile` in the same directory,

```
# Makefile
python = python3
python_config = $(python)-config
CC = gcc
CFLAGS  = $(shell $(python_config) --cflags) -fPIC
CFLAGS += $(shell $(python_config) --includes)
python_libdir = $(shell $(python) -c "import sysconfig; \
    print(sysconfig.get_config_var('LIBDIR'));")
LDLIBS  = -L$(python_libdir) -Wl,-rpath=$(python_libdir)
LDLIBS += $(shell $(python_config) --libs)
LDFLAGS = $(shell $(python_config) --ldflags) -shared

bug.so: bug.c; $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) -o bug.so bug.c
bug.c: bug.pyx; $(python) -m cython -3 $<
```

and run `make`. Running `python3 -c 'import bug; bug.bug()'` again it now picks up the compiled `bug.so`, which again prints out

```
[[1 2]
 [1 2]]
```

If we now uncomment the `cdef` declaration, run `make` and `python3 -c 'import bug; bug.bug()'` again, we get

```
[[1 1]
 [2 2]]
```

which is wrong. I do not believe the `int[:, ::1]` declaration is wrong, as Cython would then complain. If I replace it with just `int[:, :]` it works. Also, if I assign to the first dimension of `a`, `a[:1, :] = 1`, it works.

Is this a known issue, or am I somehow misunderstanding this seemingly basic usage of Cython memory views?

Comment: Are you sure the input array is contiguous?

Comment: If we `print(a.flags)` (in pure Python, without compiling), we see that `a` indeed is C-contiguous, so `int[:, ::1] a` is correct. However, `print(a[:, :1].flags)` is not! I guess this is the source of the problem.

Comment: This was indeed a bug in Cython. It has now been [fixed](https://github.com/cython/cython/pull/2961).

Comment: @jmd_dk Could you please write that as an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submitted a [bug report](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/2941) and the issue has since been [fixed](https://github.com/cython/cython/pull/2961).